# Webdav compatible software to annotate PDF on Android

Tags: android, pdf, annotation, webdav

I have some PDFs that are stored on a webdav server that I would like to annotate on my Android tablet (with a stylus).

What Android app could allow me to do this?

Comment: Welcome Statistic Dean! Can you please edit your question (and tags, if appropriate) to indicate if you are looking for commercial or gratis software?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is for Academia, so a professional case but with limited money